# Skip the "First Launch"page of Visual Studio 2019

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, visual-studio-2019

I would like to skip the below screens permanently for all users, is there anything in the installation option or some registry hack that I can do. I don't want any new user to get the below 2 prompts when they launch Visual Studio for the first time.

[image: First Launch Screen]
[image: Theme Choser]

Comment: If you say not now to the first one, you're delaying the inevitable. Users will still need to sign in to authenticate the license.

Comment: when installing, we are using a command-line "vs_enterprise.exe" with the option "--productKey". So Visual studio already has a product key then why do we need to see that prompt?